# EB Garamond and amsmath \text

Tags: amsmath, luatex, ebgaramond

On my system (OSX 10.10.5; LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015); LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2) I run the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
$\text{is}$ $\text{js}$ $\text{ is}$

\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
$\text{is}$ $\text{js}$ $\text{ is}$

\end{document}
```

In the PDF output, the first two i's on the first line come out dotless. What might explain that? The phenomenon may well be specific to EB Garamond, as the output is not only correct with Latin Modern as shown, but also when I tested it with LucidaBrightOT and fbb.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should rather use `\setmainfont{Latin Modern}` instead of `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont`.  It is in general ill-advised to mix LaTeX2e font selection (`\selectfont`) with fontspec font selection (`\setmainfont`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I hadn't installed the GUST LM fonts yet.

Comment: Also, `amsmath` should be loaded *before* `fontspec`.

Comment: In general, yes. Here it does not make a difference though.

Comment: Interesting: with XeLaTeX it works OK. It seems that some “contextual” pops out. The “i” and “j” regain their dot if I precede them with U+200B (zero width space).

Comment: Looking at the Lua table for EB Garamond, I find, in the description of `i` (decimal 105), `slookups` subtable: `["ss_l_12_s"]=984069`, `["ss_l_79_s"]=984069` and `["ss_l_88_s"]=984069`. Glyph number `984069` is indeed the dotless i. Somehow one of these lookups is active at the start of `\text`. The example can be simplified: just try `\mbox{i}`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that when `i` is the first node in a horizontal list some “contextual” is activated and `luaotfload` substitutes the `i` with the character in position 984069, that's indeed a dotless i (it's in the Private Use Area).

Looking in the Lua table for EBGaramond, I find this description for the glyph 105 (that is, the “i”):

```
  [105]={
   ["anchors"]={
    ["basechar"]={
     ["Anchor-7"]=168,
     ["Anchor-8"]=167,
     ["Anchor-9"]=165,
    },
   },
   ["boundingbox"]=166,
   ["class"]="base",
   ["index"]=74,
   ["name"]="i",
   ["slookups"]={
    ["ss_l_12_s"]=984069,
    ["ss_l_26_s"]=983201,
    ["ss_l_27_s"]=983403,
    ["ss_l_28_s"]=983302,
    ["ss_l_29_s"]=983504,
    ["ss_l_65_s"]=983605,
    ["ss_l_79_s"]=984069,
    ["ss_l_88_s"]=984069,
    ["ss_latn_l_1_s"]=983123,
   },
   ["width"]=245,
  },
```

so it seems that the culprit is one among the substitution rules `ss_l_12_s`, `ss_l_79_s` and `ss_l_88_s`. The behavior is triggered only with the `mode=node` set.

Minimal LuaTeX example:

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\testA="EBGaramond:mode=node;"
\font\testB="EBGaramond:mode=base;"

\testA

\hbox{i}i

\testB

\hbox{i}i

\bye
```

[image]

Thus `\hbox{i}` prints the dotless i at position 984069 (confirmed by doing `\showoutput` or equivalent method) when `mode=node` is active, but not when `mode=base` is used.

Such a behavior doesn't happen with XeLaTeX.

Workaround: use `Renderer=Basic`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

$\text{is}$ $\text{js}$ $\text{ is}$

\end{document}
```

[image]